# Folder explorer options

Tags: c#, .net, html, sharepoint

I have recently been assigned a task which sounded relatively simple!

Upon attempting it became clear it wasn't as straight forward as i first imagined!!!

I am trying to download multiple files to one location on the users machine. They select these files from lists within a custom share-point web part. Thats the bit i have managed to get working! The downloading is done via WebClient (System.Net.WebClient)

I now want to allow the user to select a location on their local machine to download the files to.

I thought i would be able to use  but after attempting this i realized i can only pick files :( in order to get the desired location which will confuse the user

I want something similar to the above but i only need it to return a path location like c:\Temp or any other location the user prefers on their local machine.

Could anyone suggest a control that could provide this functionality. It can also be a share-point control.

In the meantime I will be attempting Tree view as i have never used these before and these may have the power to do this from what i have read

Cheers

Truez

Clarity on language ASP.NET

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using ASP.Net/MVC/Vanilla HTML or otherwise ?

Comment: This may be unhelpful or off-topic, but you would typically deliver an archive (eg zip file) to solve this type of problem. Of course, depending on the use the files will be put to, the user might need to run (if self-extracting archive) or otherwise extract the archive, once it's in place.

Comment: I went on to add all the files to a zip file and download that zip file by forcing the browser to display it's download dialog. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this without some kind of active content, like a Flash control or *spit* activeX */spit*.
It seems strange at first, but you have to consider that this kind of functionality would let a site discover the structure of anyones storage devices; this is not 'a good thing'™

However, perhaps a different approach might solve the problem?

Why are you using WebClient, can't you provide the link to the client and let them choose their own download folder ?

Comment: it's the first time i had tried to download a group of files to one location and the WebClient class just seemed to fit the bill! I am using the webclient.DownloadFile(url,directoryToSaveTo)...I am open to suggestions..I'm not overly sure i understand what you mean by providing a link and let them choose

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is this a web app or a windows app ? If it's a web app, WebClient would just download onto the server as it doesn't run on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up zipping the files in to one folder and passed the file to be downloaded through the browser! Thanks for your comments!